# Installshield limited edition Shortcut looking for installer every reboot

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield-2010

I have Visual Studio 2013 ultimate and have created a project with Installshield limited edition.

I've added a shortcut to the result of a project in the same solution.

Once we are on production environments, we install the product with a user with administrator privileges, but we always set the option "For all Users".

Then users with "normal" user permissions use the product without problems.

Until.... they reboot, then when the users use the shortcut always looks for the installer, if we use only the exe without the shortcut everything goes fine.

I'ven't found any property that states such behavior.

I thought it could be due some AD setting but that was also ruled out.

Any one can explain me this behavior?.

BR

Jorge

Comment: Well... I forgot to mention that I have an "auto-update" exe which replaces the files with newer versions from a web server. THIS seems to be the problem. I'd like to prevent installshield to try to repair it self though

Answer (score 0):

Well... First of all I had to understand a lil' bit about the self-heal feature
http://msiworld.blogspot.com/2008/10/difference-between-self-heal-and-repair.html

Nevertheless, as stated the problem was due the auto-update feature that replaced so me files with new versions of them.

So the solution I applied was to create a lnk file and include it as content file in the main project, then we add the content result into the desktop.

So for now it works for me. Hope it works for someone else.